# acroform field values is not working in icepdf

Tags: java, pdf, itextpdf, icepdf

I am working on a project that should read a pdf file/form that contains value filled up by a Java code.

```
form.setField("permitnumber", p.getApplicationorno());
            form.setField("amountpaid", p.getAmount_app());
            form.setField("estimatedfeet", "56");
            form.setField("receiptnumber", "123415");
            form.setField("validity", "5");
```

Now my problem is, the values that were set on the fields of the pdf form worked perfectly on Adobe PDF Reader but not on the ICEPdf Viewer. What I am missing here? Why is it that the values from PDF form can't be displayed by ICEPdf?

Comment: Which PDF library did you use to fill in the values? Can you share a sample PDF?

Comment: i am using iText to fill in the values in the PDF...

Comment: Depending on the source document and your code iText does or does not create form field appearances. What's your mileage?

Comment: i created the document from OpenOffice Draw application... exported as Interactive PDF... and the code to fill in the values is mentioned in the question: 

form.setField("fieldname", "value");

Comment: Ooo has a history of creating PDFs with **NeedsAppearances** set to true. Can you provide a sample PDF?

Answer (score 0):

While setting the field values using iText, If `af` is your `AcroFields` instance, try to do

```
af.setGenerateAppearances(true);
```

before setting values.

---

The PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) defines a **NeedAppearances** flag, cf. Table 218 – *Entries in the interactive form dictionary*. If it is set to **true**, a PDF viewer knows that it has to create appearance streams for form fields.

iText interprets that flag and only creates appearance streams while filling in forms if the flag is not **true** (if **true**, the viewer is expected to re-create such appearances anyways).

Ooo at least used to create PDF forms with that flag set to **true**. Adobe Reader does respect the flag and creates appearances if **true**. Probably your PDF viewer does not respect the flag, probably it always expects appearances to already exist in documents.

Using `setGenerateAppearances(true)` you can enforce appearance stream generation. If the above assumption is correct, this should fix your problem.